# How to alter Bootstrap while keeping the mobile responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know we can alter Bootstrap default classes by writing our classes. But when i do it i lose the mobile responsiveness that comes in through the Bootstrap Framework. Is there a way to alter default Bootstrap classes and still keep the mobile responsive feature of the Bootstrap or will i have to write media queries separately to fit with customised classes

For Example this is through Bootstrap

```css
.my-nav{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: cornflowerblue !important;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.my-nav a{
  margin-left: 15% !important;
  margin-top:5%;
}
.my-nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
.my-nav li{
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar my-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="brand.png">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</header>
```

This is the sheet containing my custom classes to alter default Bootstrap classes.

How to alter Bootstrap while keeping the mobile responsiveness ??

Comment: Question to your question - why would you need to rename bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float` alongwith bootstrap to adjust your layout. It is not always a bad thing but it is when the bootstrap is using `float` on the same element and the result may not be good.

Bootstrap provides you with some predefined classes to help you. For example, to get your menu on the right instead of using `float:right;` on your menu `ul` , add `class="navbar-right"` to it, which is predefined class by it. It is good to familiarize yourself with such classes.

Second thing is to use `media queries`, which is what responsive design is all about. With bootstrap same css style may give different results in different screen sizes, so you need to involve media queries in your css.

```css
.my-nav{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: cornflowerblue !important;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.my-nav .navbar-header{
  height:80px;
}
.my-nav li{
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
    <nav class="nav navbar-default navbar my-nav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="brand.png">
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: no problem. let me know if you face any issue. also please dont forget to accept it if it helps you.